# How to export mutiple modules from a package?

Tags: node.js, module, npm, package

I am pretty new to node, and most probably this is a pretty simple problem.

Let's say I have a package `mypackage`. In the `package.json` of my package I have defined the `main` key:

```
...
"main": "./dist/index.js",
...
```

In the `dist` folder there is another module called `tools.js`

Once `mypackage` is installed, I can run node on that folder, and do the following:

```
> require('mypackage')
```

Which works perfectly. However, when I try to import the `tools` module, I run into this:

```
> require('mypackage/tools')

Error: Cannot find module 'mypackage/tools'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:438:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:386:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at repl:1:1
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:272:27)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:441:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
```

However, it works if I specify the `dist` folder:

```
> require('mypackage/dist/tools')
```

But this is not what I would like my users to do. What project structure should I follow if I have both `src` and `dist` and would like non main modules to be reachable with `mypackage/otherMod`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

because you still in the parent directory.

inside "dist/index.js" you can do

```
process.chdir(__dirname);
```

update:
You can include this using the . inside index.js do:

```
require('./tools.js');
```

Comment: The first approach means that importing my package would automatically change the pwd of the node process, which I think it is a bad idea. The second one would work, but `tools` would be available as object within `index`, and I would like that `tools` is exposed as a separate module.